# IntelliJ IDEA: how to quickly navigate to a file?

Tags: intellij-idea, keyboard-shortcuts

My project in IntelliJ IDEA has many files grouped in many folders.

Each time I want to find a specific file, I browse through the folders, then browse through the files which is boring.

Can I locate a file by typing some initial characters of its name or similarly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> I think

See http://tanu.wordpress.com/2010/09/24/moving-from-eclipse-to-intellij-idea/ for a list of shortcuts

Answer (score 4):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd>

There will be a popup, start writing some part of the filename. Pressing the key combination one more time while writing will `Include non-project files` in the search, for instance files from libraries.

[image: IDEA Enter file name]

The popup is smart, so you can write small parts of the filename to quickly filter the list. Example:
[image: IDEA Quick]

You can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> for classes, or press <kbd>Shift</kbd> twice for Search Everywhere.

Answer (score 4):

<kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> in IntelliJ IDEA 13.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>N</kbd> to search files.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>N</kbd> to search classes.